# How do I have a form on one page with the action on another page in CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I am writing a page for the admin panel i am making that lists member results.  I want to have a search form on this page to search for certain members.  Since I have other forms on this page, the action of this search form has to be in a different method in my controller.  The problem is that none of the post values are being transmitted to the search method.  What am i doing wrong?

```
class Users extends MY_Controller {

   function __construct(){
      parent::__construct();
   }

  function index(){

      if(!$this->form_validation->run()){

         $this->load->view('users/index');

      }

   }

   function search(){

       $criteria = $this->input->post('search_criteria');

   }

}
```

This is something like what my view would be:

```
<?php echo form_open('users/search'); ?>
<input type="text" name="search_criteria">
```

Answer (score 0):

You have no [form validation rules](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#setting-validation-rules) and form validation was on wrong function

```
class Users extends MY_Controller {

function __construct(){
  parent::__construct();
  $this->load->library('form_validation');
  $this->load->helper('form');
  $this->load->helper('url');
}

function index(){
   // There is no need to use index on your view files.
   $this->load->view('users');
}

function search(){

    $criteria = $this->input->post('search_criteria');

    $this->form_vadliation->set_rules('search_criteria', 'Search', 'required');

    if($this->form_validation->run() ==  FALSE) {

        // There is no need to use index on your view files.
        $this->load->view('users');

    } else {

        // Success Stuff

    }

}

}
```

View  application > views > users.php

```
<?php echo validation_errors('<div class="error">', '</div>'); ?>

<?php echo form_open('users/search'); ?>

<input type="text" name="search_criteria" value="" class="" placeholder="" />

<input type="submit" value="Save" />

<?php echo form_close();?>
```